# AR(1) process with non gaussian innovations

Tags: r, time-series

i want to simulate an AR(1) process with non gaussian innovations.
i tried it on the following way, but i`m not sure:

```
n<-25
e=rpareto(n,2,1) #can i take any distribution i want for my innovations

phi=0.2
PAR=rep(0,n)
for(t in 2:n) 
{
PAR[1]<-1
PAR[t]<-phi*PAR[t-1]+e[t]
}
```

and another way:
in the R-function arima.sim the innovations are N(0,sigma) distributed, but i want to
generate N(m,sigma) innovations.

```
sigma<-2
mu<-10
arima.sim(n=25,model=list(order=c(1,0,0),ar=0.2), sd=sqrt(sigma))+mu
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Just supply the innovations as the argument `innov`:

```
# The first problem:
e1<-rpareto(25,2,1)
arima.sim(n=25,model=list(order=c(1,0,0),ar=0.2), innov=e1)

# And the socond:
sigma<-2
mu<-10
e2<-rnorm(25,mean=mu,sd=sqrt(sigma))
arima.sim(n=25,model=list(order=c(1,0,0),ar=0.2), innov=e2)
```

Comment: I have a similar problem:
but i want to simulate an other process not by choosing the function 
"ugarchspec"
In this case it is not possible to choose any distribution as innovation.

Is there also a possibility to change the innovations of the process?

thanks for help

Comment: There is a parameter called `distribution.model`, look at it. Consider asking a separate question, maybe someone can help you.

Comment: thanks, but none of the valid distributions helps me. I need to simulate the process with other innovations.